# Wrapping an Unmanaged C++ Class Library with C++/CLI - Question 1 - Project/Code Organization

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli, wrapper, code-organization

**Note:** This post represents Question #1 of my inquiry.  The introduction block (all text until the numbers are reached) is repeated in both questions as it is background information that may be needed to answer the question.

---

#### Introduction to Question

I have an unmanaged C++ library that contains classes and functions that are common to and shared among several "higher level" libraries.  I now have need to provide access to the common library to C#/.Net applications.  To do this, I will have to wrap the common library with C++/CLI wrapper classes.

The classes contained in the common library can be complex classes containing nested class definitions and member variables that are collections of other class objects.  The collection variables are instances of typedefs of a custom list class for managing the collection.  The common library also includes classes that represent the parsed structure of a custom script file syntax created using FLEX/BISON.  The common library and the "higher level" libraries are all written in a fashion that allows for cross platform (Linux and GCC) compiling and usage.  Any changes I make must still allow for this.

The C++/CLI wrapper classes at first need only read capability.  But as the project advances, I'll eventually need to be able to create and modify the objects as well.

I know C++/CLI and have created several wrappers for other unmanaged C/C++ projects as well as providing abstracted functionality to this same common library.  So I have the basics (and some advanced knowledge) already.

I have two questions related to performing this task and since they could both spawn their own discussions and solutions, I'm splitting my questions into separate posts.  I'll include the link to the other question in each post.

---

#### Actual Questions

1. How do I structure my files within the project?

   - The namespace and class names between the unmanaged and C++/CLI projects will not conflict.  As the unmanaged project uses the "C" prefix for class names while the C++/CLI does not.  So unmanaged class `CWidget` will become just `Widget`.  And they use different root namespace names.
   - The issue comes when file names are concerned.  As my default naming pattern would be to use `Widget.h` and `Widget.cpp` for both unmanaged and C++/CLI.
   - The projects are currently setup where all files of the project are in the root of the project folder.  Includes for header files are done as just the name of the header (e.g. `#include "Widget.h"`).  And to appropriately resolve includes for files of a different project, the path of the other project is added to the `Additional Include Directories` property of the using project.
   - If I change my `Additional Include Directories` property to be the root of the solution (`..\`) and do my include for the unmanaged header as `#include "Unmanaged\Widget.h`, I have a new issue of resolving headers included in the unmanaged header.  So using that option would require I change *all* include statements to prefix their project directory.  I know other projects
   - The most obvious/quickest solution to the issue of duplicate file names is to change the naming pattern for one of the libraries.  So for the C++/CLI project, instead of using `Widget.h` and `Widget.cpp` to prefix or suffix `m` (managed) or `w` (wrapper).  So the C++/CLI files would be `mWidget.h`, `wWidget.h`, `WidgetM.h`, or `WidgetW.h`.  Then I could just repeat my existing pattern throughout and be good.
   - But is there a better way to organize the files so that I could keep my pre-/suffix-less file names with minimal changes to existing code?
2. [Wrapping an Unmanaged C++ Class Library with C++/CLI - Question 2 - Collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819801/wrapping-an-unmanaged-c-class-library-with-c-cli-collections)

Comment: I would always include the project when including header.

Comment: +1 - Well written and well thought out question.

Answer (score 2):

I have done something very similar when wrapping an unmanaged C++ api. In my case, even the class names were identical. Here's what I did with my project:

- My C++/CLI solution was at `C:\Foo`
- The unamanaged C++ api was at `C:\Foo\api`
- Every .h file (`bar.h`) started with `#include "api/bar.h"`
- All usage of unmanaged classes was via `Api::Bar`

In my case, the majority of time spent on the project was on automating the creation of the managed C++ files. I did a couple by hand, realized how much time it would take to do everything that way, and started automating the process.

My libraries were still separate. I had one unmanaged dll and one managed dll. I just stored the unmanaged project under the managed one.

As for the automation, it would read each unmanaged .h file and create my managed .h file like this:

- Add my `#include "api/bar.h"` line.
- Copy all `#include` lines.
- Add my managed namespace.
- Duplicate the class as a managed class, including the base class.
- Add a protected pointer to the unmanaged class.
- Add a function `GetInner()` to get the unmanaged class pointer.
- Add a finalizer to delete the unmanaged class.
- Add multiple functions when a function had default parameters.

Then create the managed .cpp files like this:

- Fill in most functions with calls to the unmanaged functions
- Use `GetInner()` any time a class was included as a function paramters
- Do marshal_as to convert between strings and std::wstrings

This worked for the majority of the classes with only a little manual tweaking. The one area where it didn't work was with collection classes. Now, I think I was lucky, as every collection class was basically a wrapper around `std::vector`. I based all my managed versions on `CollectionBase`, with a constructor taking the unmanaged collection class, and a method with the following signature:

```
void ToFoo(Api::Foo& v);
```

So to go from an unmanaged collection to a managed collection was just a `gcnew`, and to go the other way was:

```
Foo* foo; //most likely a function parameter, already assigned.
Api::Foo apifoo; //name just "api" + the name of the managed Foo.
foo->ToFoo(apifoo);
```

This sort of thing was also built into the .cpp class generation for the non-collection classes.

The code for `ToFoo` would just clear the unmanaged collection, iterate through the managed collection and add each unmanaged item, via `GetInner()`. My collections weren't that big, so this worked perfectly well.

If I had to do the collection classes over again, I most likely wouldn't base them on `CollectionBase` now. I'd be much more likely to base them on `List<T>` or do something similar to what was discussed in the current answers posted to your question #2. My code was started with .Net 1.1 (no generics), so at that time, `CollectionBase` made the most sense to me.

It was hand-rolled using Regex. As the library was written very consistently, I was able to read in the entire file, use Regex to remove comments and other things that might cause problems (inline functions), then just read each line and Regex to figure out what was in it. I had things like a list of all the collections (to know when to do the collection calls above), abnormal classes (string/std::wstring), and other things I'm not remembering. I'm going to have to see if it made it into our new source control, as the project was abandoned a couple years ago.

Comment: Since I need my libraries separate, I can't embed by unmanaged in the managed project.  But maybe I do need to add the project path to every include file.  What did you do for your automated process?  And did you have any suggestions for my Question #2 (see link above)?

Comment: Thanks for the additional info Joel.  I have multiple unmanaged libraries, so from an organization I think I need to keep them all at the same root.  From my initial playing around, it looks like I'm just going to Suffix "W" to my file names for the wrapper classes (seems the easiest method to integrate).  And it appears that you can template a ref class, so I can wrap some basic functionality for handling the unmanaged object pointers there.  But it does appear it will take a while to write all the wrappers.  What tool did you use to automate?  Was it a hand rolled one using RegExes?

Comment: @CuppM - try a test with a templated ref class (see how the resulting class looks in Intellisense in VS in a pure managed project). At least in VS 2008, we noticed while working a managed DirectX wrapper that introducing templates into a C++/CLI class hierarchy causes the C# editor to fail to discover any Intellisense information about that class hierachy *ever* -- which was annoying, to say the least. Not sure if that was the entire cause, but it's worth checking out in that might be problem for you.

Comment: @Josh - I'm using VS 2010 and it appears to be working fine with templated ref classes as far as the C# goes.  At least with my method.  I'm using the templated ref class as a base class to my end wrapper that stores the unmanaged pointer, whether the manage class "owns" it, and delete it on finalize if it does own it.  There appears to be an issue with VS 2010 and any Intellisense with C++/CLI.  Regular C++ works fine, but nothing for C++/CLI even though MS bloggers said it should work.