# Wrapping an Unmanaged C++ Class Library with C++/CLI - Question 2 - Collections

Tags: .net, visual-c++, collections, c++-cli, wrapper

**Note:** This post represents Question #2 of my inquiry.  The introduction block (all text until the numbers are reached) is repeated in both questions as it is background information that may be needed to answer the question.

---

#### Introduction to Question

I have an unmanaged C++ library that contains classes and functions that are common to and shared among several "higher level" libraries.  I now have need to provide access to the common library to C#/.Net applications.  To do this, I will have to wrap the common library with C++/CLI wrapper classes.

The classes contained in the common library can be complex classes containing nested class definitions and member variables that are collections of other class objects.  The collection variables are instances of typedefs of a custom list class for managing the collection.  The common library also includes classes that represent the parsed structure of a custom script file syntax created using FLEX/BISON.  The common library and the "higher level" libraries are all written in a fashion that allows for cross platform (Linux and GCC) compiling and usage.  Any changes I make must still allow for this.

The C++/CLI wrapper classes at first need only read capability.  But as the project advances, I'll eventually need to be able to create and modify the objects as well.

I know C++/CLI and have created several wrappers for other unmanaged C/C++ projects as well as providing abstracted functionality to this same common library.  So I have the basics (and some advanced knowledge) already.

I have two questions related to performing this task and since they could both spawn their own discussions and solutions, I'm splitting my questions into separate posts.  I'll include the link to the other question in each post.

---

#### Actual Questions

1. [Wrapping an Unmanaged C++ Class Library with C++/CLI - Question 1 - Project/Code Organization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819781/wrapping-an-unmanaged-c-class-library-with-c-cli-project-code-organization)
2. How do I efficiently wrap/handle collection variables in the unmanaged classes?

   - The collection objects are typedefs of a custom template list class (`CObjectList<T>`) written to handle management of a collection of object pointers.  The collection class provides all the basic collection functionality as well as pointer management and cleanup/freeing of the objects on deconstruction.  So for `CWidget` there would be a `typedef CObjectList<CWidget> CWidgetList;` in the code.
   - Most of the classes used in the code and collection class template parameter are the class itself.  But in some cases the collection is of a base class.  This occurs in the parsed structure for the custom script FLEX/BISON parser.  For example, there is a `CCommand` class that all the other available commands inherit from.  So there would be `CSetCommand`, `CPrintCommand`, `CIfCommand`, etc.
   - I figure in order to do this, I'll have to create my collection wrapper class that maintains separate lists for unmanaged and C++/CLI classes.  The inner collection object will manage the unmanaged object, and there'll have to be a managed collection/list object to store the wrapper class for the item.
   - Is there anyone that any examples/suggestions of how to do this?  Or how to write a generic class that can take both unmanaged and C++/CLI class types as parameters?

Comment: You should edit your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819781/wrapping-an-unmanaged-c-class-library-with-c-cli-project-code-organization) (especially since it got no answers) rather than repost.

Comment: what do you mean?  The number items are the questions.  The stuff before is background information that is probably needed to know to properly answer the question.  And they were both posted within 5 minutes of each other.

Comment: you might want to make the titles of your two *different* questions 'more different'. To avoid it appearing as a repost.

Comment: Ah.  I see what you mean.  I was thinking of the names of the title as more hierarchical.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very hard question to answer, but I am going to suggest that you have a marshalling/conversion layer that converts from managed collections to unmanaged ones.  Keep your library exactly as it is, and just convert the parameters and returns.

This is what I would do if

1. The collections aren't giant
2. They aren't constantly passed back and forth all of the time.
3. You often get the collection in the client code and then do a bunch of calls on it completely in managed land.

For these reasons

1. It layers the API keeping it simpler
2. crossing the unmanaged/managed boundary can be a bottleneck and should be minimized

This would be my default approach unless I really needed access to the functionality of the lib in the datastructure (it wasn't just organized data -- but data and behavior)

Comment: The member variable collections aren't giant (in the terms I'm used to thinking of giant), but for some things they could contain a couple of hundred items.  For other collections that are not member variables, they could contain 50k+ items.

Do you have a link that provides information on this?  I did see that option when Googling for information, but everything I saw only did it with simple structs/classes and none of them had examples with a collections.

Comment: As far as your point about access to functionality of the lib, the initial phase is to provide the ability to read from the library (for example the classes representing parsed script file).  The next phase would be to allow the user to create/modify the script objects and serialize back to a script file.  The library also contains a class or reading and writing the outputs from the "higher level" libraries from a SQLite database.  So I would need to provide access to that as well.

Comment: It's tricky -- I don't think you're going to find anything worthwhile written up.  Not many people discuss complex C++/CLI wrappings of C libraries. 50k+ items should not follow my advice.

Answer (score 2):

[Lou has an excellent suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819801/wrapping-an-unmanaged-c-class-library-with-c-cli-question-2-collections/4819887#4819887) and I agree with his conditions on when that approach is good.

If instead the collections are very large, or are passed back and forth frequently, you'd be better off implementing the .NET enumerable interface but not using .NET collections.  Basically, you'd have a collection wrapper that owns a native STL collection, and an iterator wrapper that owns a native STL iterator.  The collection wrapper would implement the `IEnumerable` interface and `GetEnumerator` would create an instance of the iterator wrapper, the iterator wrapper would implement the `IEnumerator` interface.

You'd want to make yourself a helper managed class (probably a value class) that wraps the pointer to the native collection and does reference counting, like `boost::shared_ptr`.  Use stack semantics notation to make sure that the reference counting gets done automatically when the managed collection wrapper or iterator wrapper get disposed.

Comment: Yes, writing a wrapper class that implements `IEnumerable`, `IList`, etc. was what I originally envisioned.  Why would a `value class` be better than regular `ref class` for wrapping the collection?  Would the reference counting be for the number of managed wrapper classes instantiated for each of the unmanaged list items?

Comment: I meant that the reference counting pointer should be a value class.  The collection wrapper can of course be a reference class.  And the reference counting is to keep the native collection alive as long as an IEnumerator wrapper exists, even if the IEnumerable collection wrapper has been disposed.